# A Depth buffer with two different projection matrices

Tags: opengl, matrix, rendering, opengl-es-2.0

I am using the default OpenGL values like glDepthRangef(0.0,1.0);, gldepthfunc(GL_LESS); and glClearDepthf(1.f); because my projection matrices change the right hand coordinate to the left hand coordinate. I mean, My near plane and the far plane z-values are supposed to be [-1 , 1] in NDC.

The problem is when I draw two objects at the one FBO including same RBOs, for example, like this code below,

```
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glClearDepthf(1.f);
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    drawObj1(); // this uses 1) the orthogonal projection below 
    drawObj2(); // this uses 2) the perspective projection below

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

always, the object1 is above the object2.

1) orthogonal [image]

2) perspective [image]

However, when they use same projection whatever it is, it works fine.

Which part do you think I should go over?

--Updated--

Coverting Eye coordinate to NDC to Screen coordinate, what really happens?

My understanding is because after both of projections, its NDC shape is same as images below, its z-value after multiplying 2) perspective matrix doesn't have to be distorted. However, according to the derbass's good answer, if z-value in the view coordinate is multiplied by the perspective matrix, the z-value would be hyperbolically distorted in NDC.

If so, if one vertex position, for example, is [-240.0, 0.0, -100.0] in the eye(view) coordinate with [w:480.0,h:320.0], and I clipped it with [-0.01,-100], would it be [-1,0,-1] or [something>=-1,0,-1] in NDC ?  And its z value is still same as -1, isn't it? when its z-value is distorted?

1) Orthogonal [image]

2) Perspective [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't expect that the z values of your vertices are projected to the same window space z value just because you use the same near and far values for a perspecitive and an orthogonal projection matrix.

In the prespecitve case, the eye space z value will be hyperbolically distorted to the NDC z value. In the orthogonal case, it is just linaerily scaled and shifted.

If your "Obj2" lies just in a flat plane z_eye=const, you can pre-calulate the distorted depth it should have in the perspective case. But if it has a non-zero extent into depth, this will not work. I can think of different approaches to deal with the situation:

1. "Fix" the depth of object two in the fragment shader by adjusting the `gl_FragDepth` according to the hyperbolic distortion your z buffer expects.
2. Use a linear z-buffer, aka. a [w buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering#W-buffer).

These approaches are conceptually the inverse of each other. In both cases, you have play with `gl_FragDepth` so that it matches the conventions of the other render pass.

**UPDATE**

> My understanding is because after both of projections, its NDC shape
>   is same as images below, its z-value after multiplying 2) perspective
>   matrix doesn't have to be distorted.

Well, these images show the conversion from clip space to NDC. And that transfromation is what the projection matrix followed by the perspective divide do. When it is in normalized device coords, no further distortion does occur. It is just linearily transformed to window space z according to the `glDepthRange()` setup.

> However, according to the
>   derbass's good answer, if z-value in the view coordinate is multiplied
>   by the perspective matrix, the z-value would be hyperbolically
>   distorted in NDC.

The perspective matrix is applied to the complete 4D homogenous eye space vector, so it is applied to `z_eye` as well as to `x_eye`, `y_eye` and also `w_eye` (which is typically just 1, but doesn't have to).

So the resulting NDC coordinates for the perspective case  are hyberbolically distorted to

```
         f + n        2 * f * n              B
z_ndc = ------- + ----------------- = A + -------
         n - f     (n - f) * z_eye         z_eye
```

while, in the orthogonal case, they are just linearily transformed to

```
         - 2              f + n    
z_ndc = ------- z_eye - --------- = C * z_eye + D
         f - n           (f - n)
```

For `n=1` and `f=10`, it will look like this (note that I plotted the range partly outside of the frustum. Clipping will prevent these values from occuring in the GL, of course).
[image: plot of z_clip as function of z_eye for perspective and orthogonal projection]

> If so, if one vertex position, for example, is [-240.0, 0.0, -100.0]
>   in the eye(view) coordinate with [w:480.0,h:320.0], and I clipped it
>   with [-0.01,-100], would it be [-1,0,-1] or [something>=-1,0,-1] in
>   NDC ? And its z value is still same as -1, isn't it? when its z-value
>   is distorted?

Points at the far plane are always transformed to `z_ndc=1`, and points at the near plane to `z_ndc=-1`. This is how the projection matrices were constructed, and this is exactly where the two graphs in the plot above intersect. So for these trivial cases, the different mappings do not matter at all. But for all other distances, they will.

Comment: Thank you. I think you are right but  It still gets me mixed up. Could you answer my question I just updated?

Comment: Thank you for your time.